# when to upgrade third-party components

Tags: language-agnostic, components

We are using quite a few third-party components in our project.  It seems like we are constantly getting email notifications that such-and-such component has released a new version.  We always face a quandry on the team regarding when to incorporate the new version.

We know that on one hand

- It's easier to upgrade from one version to the next than to skip versions and
- It's better to be at the latest version when you need to ask for support

But on the other hand

- It takes time to do these upgrades -- development, QA regression testing, deployment, etc. and during this time we are not developing our own features

We would like to formulate a general policy about this. For example, a possible policy could be

> as soon as the upgrade comes out,
>   wait X amount of time, then
>   incorporate the new version,
>   regardless of what else is going on in
>   the project or whether we need any new
>   features or fixes

Or...

> ignore all those upgrade emails and
>   just upgrade if you need a new feature
>   or fix

Or...

> wait till a natural slow point in
>   development (whatever that is) then
>   upgrade everything to the latest
>   version

Or... ???

Is there any research or guidelines out there regarding this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any research or guidelines out there regarding this topic?

Yes.  Ask 12 managers and you'll get 18 opinions.

> "as soon as the upgrade comes out, wait X amount of time, then incorporate the new version, regardless of what else is going on in the project or whether we need any new features or fixes".

Unthinking adherence to a schedule.  Always a good idea.

> "ignore all those upgrade emails and just upgrade if you need a new feature or fix"

"ignore"?  How will you decide "if you need a new feature or fix" if you "ignore" notifications?

I have to assume that "ignore" doesn't mean "ignore" but means something else.

> "wait till a natural slow point in development (whatever that is) then upgrade everything to the latest version"

Unthinking adherence to a schedule.  Still a good idea.

Here's the bottom line.

You have to actually **think** about the upgrade and what it means.

- Security?  High priority.  You might want to stop development, test this, and put it in immediately.
- Bug Fix?  High priority.  You've been waiting for this.  Of course you stop development, install it, and enjoy the benefits immediately.
- Random upgrade?  Low priority.  You might actually *discuss* this among developers and product owner to decide if you want it now or later.

There can't be a simple rule because there are so many different kinds of upgrades and so many different ways an upgrade will impact what you're delivering.

Answer (score 0):

One rule of thumb is to avoid updating third-party components near the end of a release or iteration -- unless there's a damn good reason to make an exception.

As you note, updating a third-party component introduces additional cost. *It also introduces additional risk.* As you approach a ship date, acceptable levels of risk decrease.

As S. Lott mentions, there are sometimes exceptions. Security updates, bug fixes and enhancements might be important to your product -- or not.